# Pulseaudio stopped working on Fedora 35 after update

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio

I just ran updates on Fedora 35 with `dnf update` and after all has been done, I rebooted.

#### First symptoms:

I tried watching a youtube video, and it wouldn't play. Youtube was buffering forever and suggested I "try to restart your device" if it doesn't start playing shortly.

I then tried a video on my deskop, which does produce sound, and **it works**, I can hear sound, etc.

I noticed, that when running `pavucontrol` none of my input devices (microphones), show any input.

I also noticed, than when playing a video or audio with `mpv`, it doesn't show up in the "Playback" tab in `pavucontrol`, yet I do hear sound, and `mpv reports this:

```
mpv bad\ apple\ instrumental.flac 
   cplayer:  (+) Audio --aid=1 (flac 2ch 44100Hz)
  ao/pulse: The stream is suspended. Bailing out.
   cplayer: AO: [alsa] 44100Hz stereo 2ch s32
```

So it seems to be using the ALSA device directly?

Obviously I cannot control volume with my pulseaudio volume plugin, etc.

#### My attempts at rectifying the problem:

I tried restarting the pulseaudio daemon with:

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio
systemctl --yser start pulseaudio
```

Now, `pavucontrol` only shows a "Dummy output", it doesn't see any of my input devices or output devices!

Playing a video on youtube now actually works, but with no sound, but I can see my browser showing up in the "Playback" tab and even a level meter showing output.

The same is happening with a file played with `mpv`:

```
mpv bad\ apple\ instrumental.flac
   cplayer:  (+) Audio --aid=1 (flac 2ch 44100Hz)
   cplayer: AO: [pulse] 44100Hz stereo 2ch s32
```

However this time, I can't hear anything, which seems logical, as only the output device is recognized. I can also see the levels showing output, but there is no audio.

I then tried to stop the daemon with `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio` again, and killed whatever was remaining with `pulseaudio -k`.
The problem now is, that the daemon keeps restarting every time, I'm running `mpv` or try to use my browser. No ammount of `pulseaudio -k` will stop pulseaudio from starting itself with the dummy output only and no input devices.

Running `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*` shows this:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  root       1104 f.... alsactl
                     polemon    2544 F.... wireplumber
/dev/snd/controlC1:  root       1104 f.... alsactl
                     polemon    2544 F.... wireplumber
/dev/snd/controlC2:  root       1104 f.... alsactl
                     polemon    2544 F.... wireplumber
/dev/snd/controlC3:  root       1104 f.... alsactl
                     polemon    2544 F.... wireplumber
/dev/snd/seq:        polemon    2543 F.... pipewire
```

And this is how far I got.
For some reason there seems to be a problem with pulseaudio or with ALSA, and I'm unsure how to solve the problem from here on.

`pactl info` shows this:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 1
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: polemon
Host Name: desk
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 15.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: auto_null
Default Source: auto_null.monitor
Cookie: e6fd:9850
```

#### Further investigation:

I was monitoring `journalctl --user -ef` while issuing a `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`, and found this:

```
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk systemd[1770]: Stopping Sound Service...
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk panel-8-pulseau[2027]: Disconected from the PulseAudio server. Attempting to reconnect in 5 seconds.
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk systemd[1770]: Stopped Sound Service.
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk systemd[1770]: Starting Sound Service...
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk pulseaudio[7299]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_03_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk pulseaudio[7299]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk pulseaudio[7299]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk pulseaudio[7299]: stat('/etc/pulse/default.pa.d'): No such file or directory
Dec 28 20:40:37 desk systemd[1770]: Started Sound Service.
Dec 28 20:41:02 desk pulseaudio[7299]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I can see the initialization failed, but I don't know where to go from here.

The directory `/etc/pulse/default.pa.d` indeed does not exist.

I then tried to run `pulseaudio -vvv` after stopping the daemon with `systemctl` and then runnning `pulseaudio -k`. After a couple attempts (pulseaudio kept restarting) I managed to run and this is what I see:

```
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/home/polemon/.config/pulse/c65f61a4c3e84f299be315ace0144549-card-database.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'card-database' database file '/home/polemon/.config/pulse/c65f61a4c3e84f299be315ace0144549-card-database.tdb'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-port-available" (index: #4; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-udev-detect.so': success
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC2 is accessible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2 is busy: no
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Loading module-alsa-card with arguments 'device_id="2" name="pci-0000_03_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"'
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus session bus c50f3068e569b911e3dd80c9a958124a as :1.255
D: [pulseaudio] reserve-wrap.c: Device 'Audio2' already locked.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_03_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2 (alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1) failed to load module.
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC1 is accessible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1 is busy: no
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Loading module-alsa-card with arguments 'device_id="1" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"'
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus session bus c50f3068e569b911e3dd80c9a958124a as :1.256
D: [pulseaudio] reserve-wrap.c: Device 'Audio1' already locked.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1 (alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0) failed to load module.
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC0 is accessible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/sound/card0 is busy: no
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Loading module-alsa-card with arguments 'device_id="0" name="usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"'
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus session bus c50f3068e569b911e3dd80c9a958124a as :1.257
D: [pulseaudio] reserve-wrap.c: Device 'Audio0' already locked.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/sound/card0 (alsa_card.usb-MICE_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_201308-00) failed to load module.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 3 cards.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #5; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-jackdbus-detect.so': failure
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so': success
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluetooth-policy" (index: #9; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-bluetooth-discover.so': success
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-bluez5-discover.so': success
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus system bus 1e8b84c239532ac8ec203f444f9e5c24 as :1.207
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluez5-discover" (index: #11; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluetooth-discover" (index: #10; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-esound-protocol-unix.so': failure
E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-gsettings.so': failure
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: Restoring default sink 'auto_null'.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: configured_default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: Restoring default source 'auto_null.monitor'.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: configured_default_source: (unset) -> auto_null.monitor
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #13; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module-always-sink.c: Autoloading null-sink as no other sinks detected.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring volume for sink auto_null: front-left: 65536 / 100%,   front-right: 65536 / 100%
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring mute state for sink auto_null: unmuted
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 0 "auto_null" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "abstract"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 0 "auto_null.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Thread starting up
D: [null-sink] util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [null-sink] util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: INIT -> IDLE
D: [pulseaudio] source.c: auto_null.monitor: state: INIT -> IDLE
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_source: (unset) -> auto_null.monitor
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-null-sink" (index: #15; argument: "sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #14; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #16; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink auto_null becomes idle, timeout in 5 seconds.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #17; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-console-kit.so': success
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-15.0/modules/module-systemd-login.so': success
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 0 "Login Session 2"
D: [pulseaudio] module-systemd-login.c: Added new session 2
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: exit_idle_time: 20 -> 0
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-systemd-login" (index: #18; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #19; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] stream-interaction.c: Using role 'phone' as trigger role.
D: [pulseaudio] stream-interaction.c: Using roles 'music' and 'video' as cork roles.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-role-cork" (index: #20; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-heuristics" (index: #21; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-apply" (index: #22; argument: "").
W: [pulseaudio] cli-command.c: stat('/etc/pulse/default.pa.d'): No such file or directory
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus session bus c50f3068e569b911e3dd80c9a958124a as :1.258
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Got org.PulseAudio1!
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Got org.pulseaudio.Server!
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup complete.
```

*(irrelevant lines omitted)*

I'm wondering if the database is corrupted in some way, but I really don't know.

#### Partial success:

I got some advice on IRC about how Pipewire is supposed to replace Pulseaudio. I thought that perhaps in my case, this sort of update process got awry, and I perhaps should help things along.

With `dnf` I installed the following packages:

- pipewire-pulseaudio
- pipewire-gstreamer
- pipewire-utils

This required the option `--allowerasing` as the `pulseaudio` package **got uninstalled in the process**.
I was advised this shall not be a big problem, as thanks to pipewire-pulseaudio, I'd be still able to use tools like `pavucontrol`, etc.

I was also advised to keep `wireplumber` instead of replacing it with `pipewire-media-session`.

As a result - after a reboot, my sound works - kinda. There are still problems with this setup:

- I cannot hot-plug devices. If I plug in say a new microphone, it will not be available to me with `pavucontrol`.

This is very unsatisfactory. This isn't a big deal with things like webcams, as I can still use other microphones, but if I unplug a microphone it becomes unavailable to me until I reboot (I haven't tried restarting the server yet, I'm still finding my way around pipewire).

Comment: I'm not sure but should it not be only 1 soundserver?  pulseaudio or pipewire? but pipewire is unknown land for me.

Comment: @nobody I'm not sure, but I can't just uninstall it. If I try, `dnf` tries to uninstall `gnome-shell` which is a little worrying. I don't use Gnome, I use XFCE, but still it's just all weird.

Comment: then try first something other. can you stop pipewire ? I think it is also an `systemctl --user -a | grep pipewire`  systemd user service and the socket.  stop both and restart pulseaudio.

Comment: I have been facing similar problems on Debian lately. I came across an older post where someone had this problem after an update, and her solution was to step back to using the kernel from before the update. I am not familiar with Fedora, but assumes is uses Grup or similar and that you can select older kernes on boot until you directly uninstall them. So could you try and boot with older kernel and se if that changes anything?

Comment: @nobody I'm currently trying to do the opposite and get rid of pulseaudio in favor of pipewire as it seems to be the current trend forward.

Comment: @Otzen sure, I could revert to an older kernel, but that wouldn't be fixing the issue, rather it would be just postponing it. And yes, Fedora also uses Grub2.

Comment: @polemon Sorry I'm curious do you have sound in youtube-videos with pipewire?

Comment: Not to draw attention away from this platform, but are you noticing that you might not be alone with the issue? https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/no-sound-after-upgrade/18964?u=ingli reports something seemingly similar as a common issue.

Comment: @polemon Well yes changing back to older kernel is not the permanent solution, but if this makes a difference, it is a strong indication as to where the root cause is.

Comment: @nobody Indeed it does work fine. I've been using pipewire for over a month now. The behavior is it mostly works, but I'm experiencing erratic behavior and random errors (audio devices disappearing, standard device changing) seemingly at random, usually after waking up from suspend.